# some characters is not visible well in joomla 1.5

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla1.5

I installed joomla 1.5 in English language. I also installed Joomla Danish language pack and Joomfish to make my site multilingual. I made one custom component for my site, I also made language files for it in english and danish folders in language folder. Site is well visible in Danish language but for this custom component, some danish characters like æ, ø and å are not visible well. These danish characters are showing like �. Please help me.

Comment: What content type is specified in the template?

Comment: Sidenote: v.1.5 is soon due to retirement. While in time, you should go for the 2 series

Answer (score 0):

See if your html head has

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" ; content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and check if your db charset is configured to utf-8 too

Comment: Yes... It have this.
For other default components these characters are well visible

Answer (score 0):

Data in the database must be stored using UTF-8 as well as files of your custom component.